# Xcode 4 doesn't show "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in debug area. Why not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, xcode4

I'm intentionally creating an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" fault..
The app crashes of course, BUT the debugger somehow lacks the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" message..
Why is that?

This is the code I'm using:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Foo"];
NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:str, nil];
[str release];
[a release];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

And this is the debugger log:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 41313.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)
```

Comment: What is the profile you are using Developer or distribution?

Comment: Just releasing an object does not change the object, it's memory will exist for some unspecified amount of time. So a crash might not happen referencing the memory right away.

Comment: The crash happens all the time. The lack of any message is the problem

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to regurgitate what was told to me asking a similar question to a colleague, I was told it is the Apple equivalent to "object instance not set to an instance of an object". The debugger will sometimes show the dump of what (may have) caused it, and other times completely ignore it. I'm sure there is a rhyme to the reason, but it could very well be somewhere hidden in the documents deep in the halls of Apple. Up to this point, I have never found any patterns with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS dumps (or lack thereof). I have just learned to overlook the missing info and start looking for pointer issues!

Although not overly helpful, I figured I would share this anyway!

Comment: Well that's a start I suppose.. What do you mean by "looking for pointer issues"?

Comment: Oh, I tend to release pointers in the wrong spots, etc. Thats the first thing I check.

Answer (score 0):

May be an issue with NSLog... Try another way to create a segfault. For instance:

```
char * str;

str      = ( char * )666;
str[ 0 ] = 0;
```

Comment: I'd like to create a segfault for an NSObject member so I'll be able to use NSZombie later on...